# "Impossible to access an attribute on a NULL variable"

Tags: templating, plugin-duktvideos

I am getting this error returned whilst in Debug mode:

> Template Error
>
> Impossible to access an attribute ("gatewayHandle") on a NULL variable ("")

Not sure why this is getting flagged up. It is a variable which is accessed through the Dukt Video plugin? Seems to work when not in debug mode, but I am getting slow initial response times when loading, not sure if this is related to that issue.

I have attached the relevant page code:

```
{# Video Link :: if entry is of video type #}

{% if entries.section == "Videos" %}

    {% set video = entries.video %}

    {% if video.gatewayHandle == 'youtube' %}
        <a
            data-target="flare"
            href="http://youtu.be/{{ video.id }}"
        >
    {% else %}
        <a
            data-target="flare"
            href="http://vimeo.com/{{ video.id }}"
        >
    {% endif %}

{% else %}

{# Entry link #}

<a href="{{ entries.url }}">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Daryl, looks like you accidentally posted this in the "Meta" section... I'll go ahead and move it back to the main Stack Exchange site for you.

Answer (score 2):

That message is telling you that `gatewayHandle` can't be accessed from `video`, because `video` is `NULL`. You're expecting the videos field to always contain an object, but in this case it is not.

I would suggest that you ensure that `video` actually contains a value before you attempt to reference one of its properties...

```
{% set video = entries.video %}

{% if video %}

    {% if video.gatewayHandle == 'youtube' %}
        ...
    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be: `{% set video = entries.video.first %}`?

Comment: Could be, that's probably why it's returning `NULL`. I didn't think much about his data structure, just simply telling him what that error meant, and how to protect against it.